# If $f$ is one-to-one function has horizontal asymptote at $y- a$ , then the function $f^{-1}(x)$

Tags: functions, polynomials

**The chooses are :**

A- Has a vertical asymptote at x = a

B- Has a vertical asymptote at x = -a

C- Has a horizontal asymptote at y = a

D- Has horizontal asymptote at y= -a

---

I've tried to find function like this but i couldnt find anything other $f(x)=1/x$ which is the same as its inverse

Answer (score 1):

If a function has horizontal asymptote at $y=a$ then its inverse has a vertical asymptote at $x=a$ because inversing a function is like mirroring it about the line $y=x$.